# What is the T-SQL syntax to round a value to the nearest decimal based on this specific logic?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, decimal, rounding

I am using `SQL Server 2014`and I have the following T-SQL syntax in my SQL query:

```
Select ...    
NumDays/30 as 'NumMonth',
...
```

NumDays is the total number of days and the syntax above converts it into month.
My problem is that if I have NumDays = 508, its equivalent NumMonth becomes 16.

However, 508/30 = 16.93333
I want the result to be 17, based on the logic that if the result is >= 16.5, then it displays 17, else it displays 16.

Neither the `CEILING` nor `FLOOR` functions seem to be the right solution, as per rounding solutions presented on this web page: [SQL Server ROUND, CEILING and FLOOR Examples for Decimal, Numeric and Float Data Types](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1589/sql-server-rounding-functions--round-ceiling-and-floor/)

Comment: `SELECT ROUND(16.5,0)` does what you need

Comment: integer divide by integer will gives you the result in integer. In you case you want the result in decimal and then round to integer. use `NumDays / 30.0` and then convert() to integer or round() it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
Declare @NumDays INT = 508
        ,@i INT = 30

SELECT CAST( ROUND(CAST(@NumDays AS DECIMAL(18,2))
                     / CAST(@i AS DECIMAL(18,2)) , 0) AS INT)
```

Convert it to decimal before you divide it, to keep the decimal part of the value.

Comment: exactly what i needed! Thanks.